# Doesn't switch to another View with NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.searchResults) { item in
                                if ((item.profile_path?.isEmpty) != nil) {
                                    NavigationLink{
                                        PersonDetailView(cast: castModel.searchcastdata)
                                    } label: {
                                        SearchCard(searchitems: item)
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                            Task {
                                                do {
                                                    await castModel.loadCastProfiles(castid: item.id)
                                                    print("CASTDATATATA \(String(describing: castModel.searchcastdata))")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                } else {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: ContentDetailView(searchitems: item),
                                        label: {
                                            SearchCard(searchitems: item)
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

After receiving the data in the Task in the SearchCard(searchitems: item) section, I want it to move to another View with that data. When I click it, I see in the console output that it has successfully received the data, but I cannot switch to PersonDetailView(). How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Because the tap gesture is likely invalidating the gesture for the link. It isn’t a good idea to mix gestures like this. Use task, onAppear, append to a navigation path, etc.

Comment: A ```NavigationLink``` only works when it is inside a ```NavigationStack``` (or ```NavigationSplitView```). So make sure it is.

Comment: One more probable issue can be that the Navigation Link tap gesture has been overriden by the .onTap gesture. So only the .loadCastProfiles fuction is executed but the navigation is not happening.